# how to add values of looped variable to table and call the table in another function

Tags: matlab, datatables, functional-programming, structure

```
for it=1:10
    x=rand(10,1)
    y=x.^2
    datastore=table(i,x,y)   % all iteration values are not stored
end

function z=summation(x,y)
z=x+y  %here I want to call table for other math operations also
end
```

Make a table and store value of i, x and y of each iteration. I want to avoid the use of global variables and use function or variable scoping, whichever is the most appropriate.
How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your loop. First of all, I'm assuming it's a typo and `for it=1:10` should be `for i=1:10`. Second, you're overwriting your `database` variable on each iteration of the loop.

Why does the data have to be stored into a table? You could just as easily do this in a singular loop.

```
for i=1:10 % define loop variable
x(:,i)=rand(10,1); % generate random vector and store into 'i'th column of x
y(:,i)=x(:,i).^2; % find 2nd power of vector, store into 'i'th column of y
z(:,i) = x(:,i) + y(:,i); % summate 'i'th vector of x and y and store in z
end
```

Or if you really want, you can just make a table with x and y by doing `table(x,y)` after the loop and pass the table into your function.

Comment: Part of question is how to call it another function, without globals. And with variable or function scoping. Can you please extend it bit more?

Comment: Define the table after the loop and then put your table into the function as `function z = summation(table)`